# How to set style after loading a value from localStorage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-core

I want to load a value from localStorage and then at page load set a style='display:none' or not on a table row.

One possibility I see is:

```
<script>
   if(localStorage.getItem('test') == 'aja')
   {
      document.write('<tr style="display:none">');
   }else{
      document.write('<tr>');
   } 
</script>
```

but that doesn't seem to be a good solution as the editor doesn't recogize this and is then complaning about the missing

I could also hide it at after page load - but then it is visible for a split second before it is hidden - not ideal.

I am somewhat missing the possiblity to directly use variables in the html code itself. Like Razor / c# is doint it

```
@var hiddenOrNot = 'none';
<tr style="display:@hiddenOrNot">
```

but that is loaded on the server side, so no possibility to get the localStorage value...

Any suggestion? jquery or javascript

Thanks a lot

Comment: Close your table row tag?? `document.write('<tr style="display:none"></tr>');` or `document.write('<tr></tr>');`

Comment: Don't use document.write to start with.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this perhaps.

- Select the row that needs to be removed if condition true
- Create a class that contains style `display:none`
- Add class to row if condition true

```js
let tr = document.querySelector(".testRow");
let localStorageItem = localStorage.getItem("test") || "";

tr.classList.add((localStorageItem === 'aja') ? "hideRow" : null);
```

```css
.hideRow {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="testRow">
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

*Edit: error on console here is due to StackOverFlow not allowing access to localStorage, should work fine on your system*

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set tr to `display: none` by default,and if `localStorage.getItem('test') != 'aja'` remove it.So that it will not be visible for a split second before it is hidden.Here is a demo:

view:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr class="hidden">
            <td>Id</td>
            <td>Name</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="hidden">
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Name1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="hidden">
            <td>2</td>
            <td>Name2</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

css:

```
<style>
    .hidden {
        display: none
    }
</style>
```

js:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            if (localStorage.getItem('test') != 'aja') {
                $("tr").removeClass();
                
            }
        });
    </script>
```